# QDate is not convertible to datetime

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, pyqt5, qdate

I have a geodataframe which I'm adding some column data to, all the same length, to get this in the correct format for another application I do the following:

```
revdate = datetime.date(1999, 12, 20).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
gdf['revdate'] = revdate
gdf['revdate'] = pd.to_datetime(gdf['revdate']).dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

Incorporating PyQt5 I use a `DateEdit` field, I need to go through the same procedure as above:

```
revdate = self.dateEditRevDate.date()

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
gdf['revdate'] = revdate
gdf['revdate'] = pd.to_datetime(gdf['revdate']).dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

The date is received  This date is in format `PyQt5.QtCore.QDate(2000, 1, 1)`

It trips up on this line:

```
gdf['hs2_revdate'] = pd.to_datetime(gdf['hs2_revdate']).dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

With a type error `TypeError: <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QDate'> is not convertible to datetime`

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you are missing a ( between the gdf and [ in the statement  see example pd.to_datetime(gdf ( ['hd2_revdate'])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't get too complicated trying to use QDate as you can convert it to `datetime.date()` using the `toPyDate()` method:

```
revdate = self.dateEditRevDate.date().toPyDate().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```